# Enabling Peer, Client, Admin roles in the policies using own ca server not cryptogen

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, ca

I have successfully created a network by generating certificates using Fabric Ca server and Ca client binaries. But i am only able to use following policies in the configtx.yaml.

```
Readers:
Type: Signature
Rule: "OR('abcMSP.member')"
Writers:
Type: Signature
Rule: "OR('abcMSP.member')"
Admins:
Type: Signature
Rule: "OR('abcMSP.member')"
```

But i want to use nodeous like below.

```
Readers:
Type: Signature
Rule: "OR('abcMsp.admin', 'abcMsp.peer', 'abcMsp.client')"
Writers:
Type: Signature
Rule: "OR('abcMsp.admin', 'abcMsp.client')"
Admins:
Type: Signature
Rule: "OR('abcMsp.admin','abcMsp.client')"
```

Below is what i have added to the msp folder in the config.yaml.

```
NodeOUs:
  Enable: true
  ClientOUIdentifier:
    Certificate: "cacerts/ca.pem"
    OrganizationalUnitIdentifier: "client"
  PeerOUIdentifier:
    Certificate: "cacerts/ca.pem"
    OrganizationalUnitIdentifier: "peer"
  AdminOUIdentifier:
    Certificate: "cacerts/ca.pem"
    OrganizationalUnitIdentifier: "admin"
```

Which generate following error raft ordering service server throws.

```
Failed validating bootstrap block: initializing channelconfig failed: could not create
channel Consortiums sub-group config: setting up the MSP manager failed: admin 0 is invalid: 
The identity is not valid under this MSP [abcMSP]: could not validate identity's OUs: the 
identity must be a client or a peer identity to be valid, not a combination of them. OUs:
```

Comment: Which version of Fabric are you using?  Admin OU support was not added until 1.4.3.  Also, we'd need to see the admin certificate(s) you are trying to use in your MSP (e.g. `openssl x509 -noout -text -in admin.pem`)

Comment: @GariSingh here is the output link:
https://pastebin.com/g8AuckZb

Comment: @GariSingh Does identity classification are not supported right now that why even in  ca operations guide you have not mentioned the endorsement policy and used the default policy (-P flag and policies are missing ). Here is the link below
https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/operations_guide.html#id4

Answer (score 0):

Your admin has `OU=client` and `OU=peer` at the same time in its certificate (or something similar) when it must have  only `OU=admin`. Take into account that affiliations and departments are also included in the `OU`s, so I bet you have some affiliation or department called `client` or `peer`. If that's the case, change affiliation or department names and redeploy.

And, when registering your admin in the CA, remember to specify type `admin`, not `client`:

```
fabric-ca-client register -d --id.name $ORG_ADMIN --id.secret $ORG_ADMIN_PASSWORD --id.type admin --id.affiliation $ORG_AFFILIATION
```

**EDIT:** Looking at your admin certificate, its `OU`s do not include the required role (you specified type `user` when registering). Register and enroll your identities suitably: https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/users-guide.html#fabric-ca-client

Comment: Here is the detail from the certificate generated from cryptogen in the default first network sample.
Subject: C = US, ST = California, L = San Francisco, OU = client, CN = Admin@org1.example.com

Comment: Check your `crypto-config.yaml`. Do you have your `EnableNodeOUs` to true? https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/discovery/test/testdata/crypto-config.yaml. Check also your `cryptogen version`.

Comment: here is my certificate link pastebin.com/GZBgzjWG

Comment: Now it has better aspect. You shouldn't probably see the same error.

Comment: Does identity classification are not supported right now that's why even in  ca operations guide they have not mentioned the endorsement policy and used the default policy (-P flag and policies are missing ). Here is the link below
https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/operations_guide.html#id4

Comment: it's supported ... the fabric-samples use it (e.g. first-network uses this)

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass **OU** as **either admin, peer, client or orderer** to your certificates while enrolling them with Fabric-CA. Then only the certificate will be valid for doing particular operations using those certificates. Here is an example for generating **admin** certificate:

```
fabric-ca-client enroll --caname ca.example.com --csr.names C=SG,ST=Singapore,L=Singapore,O=$ORG_NAME,OU=admin -m admin -u http://admin:adminpw@localhost:$PORT
```

Comment: That, fortunately, does not work. The command has success, but Fabric-CA overrides OUs. Roles are defined by the CA administrator via `--id.type` during registration. Otherwise, any actor could (re-)define its own roles when (re-)enrolling its own certificates.

Comment: Okay, I am suggesting for generating new certificates(not re-enrolling) for all the identities as the generated certs were not correct. The client identity that is passed in the CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH must be of admin type.

Comment: Yeah, but try your own command in your environment with `OU=whatever` (`peer`, for instance) and check the generated certificate via `openssl x509 -text -noout -in yourpath/signcerts/cert.pem`. You'll see that your `OU` has not been included. Fortunately, as you yourself should not have permission to define your own role.

Comment: @Trinayan here is my certificate link https://pastebin.com/GZBgzjWG

Comment: Is it still not working? Are you still not able to bootstrap your admin identity?

Comment: @Trinayan no i am not.

Comment: I have done it almost similarly only thing that i have done different is that i have used LDAP as registry. So, i think there must be some other issue.